# What tweaks are necessary to create a responsive web page?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm fairly new to coding, so I know it's far from perfect! I'm just looking for some help getting this page to look decent on a mobile phone. Most likely, the text and picture will stack; I'm not sure what to do about the header and footer.

```
<body>
<h1 div id= "header"> </h1>
<div id="logos"> <img id="logo" src= "https://msu.edu/~donald88/portfolio/logo02.png" </div>
<ul id="navigation"> 
<li> <a href= "http://kelsiedonaldson.com."> About</a></li>
<li> <a href= "http://kelsiedonaldson.com/portfolio.html"> Portfolio</a></li>
 <li> <a href= "http://kelsiedonaldson.com/resume.html"> Résumé</a></li>
 <li> <a href= "http://kelsiedonaldson.com/contact.html"> Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<h2> Project Spotlight </h2>
<h3> Refugee Development Center Newsletters </h3>
</br> </br>
<div id= "main">
<div class="project-image"><img src= "https://msu.edu/~donald88/portfolio/rdcnewslettertwo.png" alt="RDC newsletter" /></div>
<div id="spotlight-text"> <p class="project-text"> This is a project I did in a class during my freshman year of college. A member of the RDC staff came to my class to 
give a general overview of what she wanted, and then we divided into teams to design two newsletters for this awesome organization. My team
consisted of three members, and we all worked together to write and design the newsletters. I specifically wrote the story pictured on the 
left in the summer 2016 newsletter about the GLOBE camp program. I also helped collaborate on the design of both newsletters as far as color choice,
text formatting, and article length. I then edited my other team members' articles and helped assemble everything as a PDF that could be printed
or looked at online. Finally, my team gave a presentation to the rest of my class and the RDC staff member about our newsletter and the choices
we made while creating it. The client only had positive things to say about our design! </p>
<p class="project-text"> Completed: April, 2016 <br/>
 Category: Web/Print </p>
</div>
<div class="back-button"> <a href= "http://kelsiedonaldson.com/portfolio.html"> Back to portfolio </a> </div>
<div class="portfolio-button"> <a href= "http://kelsiedonaldson.com/rdc_newsletters.pdf" target="_blank"> See full project </a> </div>
</div>
</p>
 <div style="clear: both"></div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="ftr-wrap">
        <div class="ftr-links">
        <div class= "table">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Kelsdonaldson22"> <div class="icons"><img src= "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/256/Twitter-icon.png"></div></a></li>     
               <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kelsie.donaldson"><div class="icons"><img src= "https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png"></div></a></li>     
               <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/kelsiedonaldson/"><div class="icons"><img src= "http://3835642c2693476aa717-d4b78efce91b9730bcca725cf9bb0b37.r51.cf1.rackcdn.com/Instagram_App_Large_May2016_200.png"></div></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kelsie-donaldson-965033115?trk=hp-identity-name"><div class="icons"><img src= "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/linkedin-512.png"</a></div></li>
            </div>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright-amazon">
            <p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright Kelsie Donaldson 2016</p>
             <p class="amazon"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/kelsiedonaldson/"><img 
        </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
Body {
background-image: url("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/velka/grey-white-background.jpg");
width: 100%;
}

html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

#header {
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1200px; 
background-color: #b196db;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Yesteryear', cursive;
margin: 0px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
line-height: 120px;
font-size: 100px;
position: relative;
}
#logo {
height: 110px;
max-width: 880px;
padding: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 28px;
margin-top: -10em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
}


#navigation li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 50px;
float: center;
text-decoration: none; }

   #navigation {
text-align: center;
min-width: 1160px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #35b7ab;
margin-top: 0px;
top: 140px;
padding-top: 15px;
font-family: Lucida bright;
font-size: 20px;
color: white
}
 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
 a:hover{
color: #867289; }

    h2 {
font-size: 50px;
color: #66096c;
font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
text-align: center; }

   html {
font-family: sans-serif;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

  body {
padding:0;
margin: 0;
}

.footer {
position: absolute;
margin-bottom: -30;
margin-top: 10px;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
min-width: 1200px;
background-color: #b196db;

}

.footer p {
color: #fff;
font-size:1em;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
float: right; 
}


.container {
max-width: 1674px;  /* adjust to allow for padding as needed */
padding:0 50px; }


    #ftr-wrap {
display:table;
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto; }

  #ftr-wrap > div:nth-child(1) {text-align:left;}
#ftr-wrap > div:nth-child(2) {text-align:center;}
#ftr-wrap > div:nth-child(3) {text-align:right;}

.ftr-links ul {
  padding: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%; }


.table {
position: relative;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin-left: 45%;
bottom: -50; }

.ftr-links ul li {
 display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
 font-size:.75em; }

.ftr-links ul li a {
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
margin: 0; }

.icons > img {
display: inline;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
padding-bottom: 20px; }

   #main{
height:800px;
width:100%; 
}

#main {
height:500px;
width:100%;
}

 .project-image{
width:40%;
color: #66096c;
height:100%;
float:left;
margin-left: 7em; 
padding-right: 3em;
}

 div#spotlight-text {
width:40%;
height:100%;
float:left;
font-family: Lucida Bright;
font-size: 20px;
color: #66096c; 
margin-right: 2%;
}
    h3 {
font-size: 30px;
color: #867289;
text-align: center;
font-family: Lucida Bright;
```

Comment: Helpful tips: changing HTML code so it is responsive is potentially hours worth of work, so would be too broad here (and most places on the web). Also, be careful of questions that are basically "please help me" - it is very common for questions asked in that fashion to slide into "do it for me". If you can break this down into "how to make two divs responsive, here is exactly what I have tried", then that would be a great question. HTH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want your page to look better when it gets scaled down to mobile but if you want to accomplish this, I highly recommend you check out [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

They can help you accomplish what you're looking for. Also, please don't forget when using media queries to put this at the closing of your head tag in your HTML document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```